# MongoDB Embedded Chart filter

Tags: mongodb, filter, mongodb-query, mongodb-charts

I am having trouble with applying MongoDB filter (the optional filters that we leave for end-user to apply). I'm using an Iframe option to show charts.

when I add an integer-based filter it works fine and returns me a number of users

*eg : (those users that age is greater than 50)*

```
filter = { "age": { $gt: 50 } }
```

But when I apply _id based filter it gives me 0

*eg Those users that parentId match with given id*

```
filter = { "parent_id" :  6t94f5c7webccea2c3e3d6856 }
```

I also check this way

```
filter = { "parent_id" :  ObjectId("6t94f5c7webccea2c3e3d6856") }
```

but non of them work.

here is my document look like

```
`{_id : ObjectId("5fe081a0689bdf07a365ddbf"), city: "Pakistan", parent_id : ObjectId("6t94f5c7webccea2c3e3d6856"), Age : 50, Name : "Test" }`
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yeah, here is my document SS [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpLGb.png)

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text.

Comment: {
_id : ObjectId("5fe081a0689bdf07a365ddbf") ,
city: "Pakistan",
parent_id : ObjectId("6fe081a0689bdfa365ddee"),
Age : 50,
Name : "Test"
}

Comment: Why do you think `"parent_id": ObjectId("6fe081a0689bdfa365ddee")` should match `"parent_id":  ObjectId("6t94f5c7webccea2c3e3d6856")`???

Comment: I want those users to count that have same parent Id

Comment: I edit the question please check

Comment: Your filter should work, most likely you have a typo.

Comment: I checked. but there is no type. Because it's working fine for integer filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no issue with you query except spacing issue
I used filters like that, and they are working fine for me, please recheck your params and try to identify any missing thing there hope it helps
filter = { "your parent id " :  ObjectId("mongoId") }

Comment: Can you add some code to help others understand this solution? MongoDB Charts is a new technology with small community. Thank you!